# Python pptx module

Tags: python, parsing, powerpoint

I have to edit a pptx template which contain tables like this:[image: pptx table]

How to append values stored in my python dict to the empty fields?
I'm using a pptx module, but I couldn't find any example of doing this.

```
from pptx import Presentation


prs = Presentation('template.pptx')
slide = prs.slides[2] #<- This is the slide that contains the table
shape = slide.shapes #<- As I understood This gives access to the shapes
textframe=shape.textframe
textframe.clear()

prs.save('test.pptx') #<- Saves the new file
```

[pptx module link](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Comment: If it's just a table, maybe it is good for you to use excel module(very easy to use) and change the file format to pptx later.

Comment: not an optional way of doing this

Comment: I'd guess that shape = slide.shapes gives you access to the shapes COLLECTION on the slide. You'd need to specify which shape contains the table. The shape's shape.table property would give you access to the table; from there you can manipulate the table's .Cell(x,y) collection. Each cell has a Shape property, which has a textframe.textrange.text value that you can plug your text into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quote from the dev-group of python-ppty developer

-if you know its index, something like `table = slide.shapes[2]` would do the trick.
Then you'll need to navigate the cells before you can change their contents:

```
for idx, row in enumerate(table.rows):
    if idx = 0:  # skip header row
        continue
    name_cell = row.cells[0]
    name_cell.text = 'foobar'
    corners_cell = row.cells[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
---in main----
table_data = [['ID', 'Name', 'Age', 'Second name'], ['1', 'Petro', 22, 'Petrovich'], ['2', 'Ivan', 32, 'Ivanovich'], ['3', 'Oles', 23, 'Marko']]

prs = Presentation(template_filepath)

slide_1 = slide_build(prs, 5)
table_draw(table_data, slide_1.shapes)
prs.save(result_filepath)


def slide_build(prs, layout):
    slide = prs.slides.add_slide(prs.slide_layouts[layout])
    return slide

def table_draw(table_data, shapes):
    rows_number = 0
    columns_number = 0

    # get table size
    rows_number = len(table_data)
    for i, item in enumerate(table_data):
        columns_number += 1

    table = table_build(rows_number, columns_number, shapes)

    column_coord = 0
    row_coord = 0

    for row_count, row in enumerate(table_data):
        for item_count, row_item in enumerate(row):
            table.cell(row_count + row_coord, item_count + column_coord).text = str(row_item)

def table_build(rows, cols, shapes):
    left = (0.1)
    top = Inches(0.7)
    width = Inches(6.0)
    height = Inches(0.8)
    table = shapes.add_table(rows, cols, left, top, width, height).table

    # set column widths
    i = 0
    while i
```

Some thing like this